# ml5.js styleTransfer only works with 1:1 aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, style-transfer

I'm experimenting with the `styleTransfer` method in [ml5.js](https://ml5js.org). It works well, but I've run into a problem where it only seems to work with square images as the input source — any other aspect ratio results in garbled output where the x/y coordinates appear interpolated.

This seems like a bug, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

I'm using the starter code found in the [ml5-examples](https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-examples/tree/master/p5js/StyleTransfer/StyleTransfer_Image) repository, specifically here:
https://github.com/ml5js/ml5-examples

You can see a functional demonstration of that code here:
https://ml5js.org/docs/style-transfer-image-example

The only thing I've changed from the original source code is that my input image is a non-square aspect ratio. [This](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/george.mand.is/me-teaching-electronic-smilies-smaller.jpg) is the image I'm using, though I've scaled it down to about 300x225 pixels.

To recreate the problem I'm trying to describe:

- Go to the [demo page](https://ml5js.org/docs/style-transfer-image-example). Click the "Transfer" button once to see how it's intended to work.
- Use the browser inspector (I'm using Chrome) and make the height and width of the input image (`#inputImg`) something like 300 by 200 pixels.
- Click "Transfer" and notice the clearly garbled result.

In contrast, an almost identical demo is setup for Deeplearn.js:

https://reiinakano.github.io/fast-style-transfer-deeplearnjs/assets/scripts/example-style-transfer-image.js

If you take similar steps and skew the aspect ratio of the input image to something other than a square the results work as expected — the output image is a style-transferred version of the input image with the same aspect ratio as the input.

DeepLearn.js is deprecated now but actually served as the base code for ml5.js as I understand it, so it' curious to me this bug doesn't exist in the original implementation.

Is there something I'm overlooking? Or is this a bug with ml5.js?

Apologies for not linking to a CodePen demo or something — it's a little tricky with the need to load models. I can try to host my code somewhere for all to see if it helps clarify the problem.

Comment: Deeplearning.js is no longer supported. tensorflow.js can be used instead

Comment: @edkeveked Thanks. I know DeepLearn.js is deprecated — I'm linking to it because the DeepLearn example works "correctly" whereas the ml5.js one does not. I double-checked and my understanding is ml5.js is built on top of tensorflow.js, for what it's worth. I'm not sure how any of this addresses my question about the image aspect ratio issue though.